# Converting networkx graph to flare json

Tags: python, d3.js, networkx

I have a networkx graph

```
g
```

And I want to draw up this visualization

http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html

What that means is somehow I have to convert my graph into flare.json

https://bitbucket.org/john2x/d3test/src/2ce4dd511244/d3/examples/data/flare.json

To convert this graph into a tree.. I will give a seed node which serves as root of this json and then grow the tree by adding edges to this tree as its children upto say 3 hops..
How do i do this?

Comment: Are looking to convert some data into `flare.json` like hierarchical data?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a tree you can use the networkx [tree_data()](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.json_graph.tree_data.html#networkx.readwrite.json_graph.tree_data) function to write the data in JSON tree format for that flare.json example.

The example shown there is:

```
>>> from networkx.readwrite import json_graph
>>> G = nx.DiGraph([(1,2)])
>>> data = json_graph.tree_data(G,root=1)
```

To build a tree from your graph either [bfs_tree()](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.traversal.breadth_first_search.bfs_tree.html?highlight=bfs_tree#networkx.algorithms.traversal.breadth_first_search.bfs_tree) or [dfs_tree()](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.traversal.breadth_first_search.bfs_tree.html?highlight=bfs_tree#networkx.algorithms.traversal.breadth_first_search.bfs_tree) would work.
Or maybe you already know how you want to build a tree from your graph.

There is an example of how to use the d3.js library with NetworkX at https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/auto_examples/index.html#javascript
That uses the d3.js force layout code.