# Convert graphviz.dot.Digraph to networkx.Graph

Tags: python, json, tree, networkx, graphviz

### Question

How do I convert a `graphviz.dot.Digraph` into a `networkx.Graph` (or any subclass of it)?

### Motivation

LightGBM, an implementation of a tree-based algorithm, has a function returning a `graphviz.dot.Digraph` object. This type of object can represent *any* directed graph, but my graph is specifically a tree, and thus can be represented in JSON via a simpler nested structure:

```
var tree = {
    "name": "parent",
    "children": [
         {
         "name": "child_1"
         }
         {
         "name": "child_2"
         }
    [
}
```

Another, longer example of the above JSON structure is [here](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1093025). I use this JSON format to create a tree visualization using `d3` in `javascript`.

In total, I need to convert this `graphviz.dot.Digraph` object to the above nested-JSON format.

*If* I can convert this `graphviz.dot.Digraph` object into a `networkx.Graph` object, I can use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21038079/converting-networkx-graph-to-flare-json) to convert it to the required JSON format. This intermediate conversion has been problematic for me. It seems I need another conversion to something `networkx` [can use](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/index.html).

Comment: Have you looked at [`read_dot`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/search.html?q=read_dot&check_keywords=yes&area=default)

Answer (score 1):

One method of converting `graphviz.dot.Digraph` to a `networkx.Graph` is to convert it to a `pydotplus.graphviz.Dot` object, and convert that into a `networkx.classes.multidigraph.MultiDiGraph` object which inherets from `graph`.

```
#--------------------
# Do whatever it is you do to create the graphviz.Digraph object
import lightgbm as lgbm

# .......
digraph = lgbm.create_tree_digraph(model)
print(type(digraph)) # prints <class 'graphviz.dot.Digraph'>


#--------------------
# Perform the conversion to networkx
import pydotplus
import networkx

dotplus = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(digraph.source)
print(type(dotplus)) # prints <class 'pydotplus.graphviz.Dot'>
# if graph doesn't have multiedges, use dotplus.set_strict(true)
nx_graph = networkx.nx_pydot.from_pydot(dotplus)
print(type(nx_graph)) # prints <class 'networkx.classes.multidigraph.MultiDiGraph'>
```

The rest is just for people considering conversion to JSON

```
#--------------------
# Optionally, convert to json
import json

# must specify whatever node is the root of the tree, here its 'split0'
#     or you can try list(graph)[0] if you're not sure.
data = networkx.readwrite.json_graph.tree_data(nx_graph,root='split0')
# data is just a dictionary. Dump results in proper json format.
json.dump(data,open(file_path,'w'))
```

Later I found out LightGBM actually has a dump_model method that shortcuts all of this...but I'll leave this here.